# Selectable grid row in asp.net with C# like istockphoto

Tags: c#, asp.net, select, grid, row

I'm building a website for a friend and would like to know how hard is it to code a selectable menu like http://www.istockphoto.com/stock-photo-8544108-beauty-with-hat.php - the one on the right where you choose picture size. I would like to create something similar in asp.net c#. 
I searched for 3 hours on google and couldn't find any solution similar or useful.
Can someone help please?

[alt text http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2009-09-25_1158.png](http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2009-09-25_1158.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is easy to accomplish

1 - create a new AJAX Enable Web Site in your Visual Studio

[alt text http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2009-09-25_1201.png](http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2009-09-25_1201.png)

2 - place an Script Manager 
3 - place an Update Panel and add the GridView and Textbox inside
4 - tell the Update panel that ChildrenAsTriggers="true"
5 - add 2 events in the grid view, RowDataBound and SelectedIndexChanged

```
<body>
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
   <asp:ScriptManager ID="sm" runat="server" />
   <div>
      <asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnl" runat="server">
         <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:GridView ID="grid" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="grid_RowDataBound" OnSelectedIndexChanged="grid_SelectedIndexChanged">
               <Columns>
                  <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
               </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
            <br />
            Credits:
            <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" Text="Label" Font-Bold="true" />
         </ContentTemplate>
      </asp:UpdatePanel>
   </div>
   </form>
</body>
```

6 - do something in both

```
protected void grid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:__doPostBack('grid','Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex + "')");
    }
}
protected void grid_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lbl.Text = "changed...";
}
```

Comment: You need to accept gears in order to see the menu. Sorry, I have the image cropped but I don;t see where to upload it on website.

Comment: you hosted in a free image hosting site, when you click in the image icon (in the StackOverflow editor) you see the link for it. I'm using JING and hosting in my own FTP (http://www.jingproject.com)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<style type="text/css">
  .selectedRow{background-color:#E8E8FF;}
</style>

<table id="selectMenu">
  <tr><th>Size</th><th>Pixles</th><th>File size</th><th>Credits</th></tr>
  <tr><td>Small</td> <td>849 × 565 px</td> <td>555.96 KB</td> <td>20</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Medium</td> <td>1698 × 1131 px</td> <td>1.89 KB</td> <td>30</td></tr>
</table>

<div style="height:50px;width:200px">
    <div style="float:right;text-align:left;">
    Total Credits: <span id="credits">&nbsp;</span>
        //YOU CAN USE ASP.net HIDDEN FIELD TO WORK ON SERVER SIDE
        <input type="hidden" id="creditsValue" value=""/>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("table#selectMenu tr td").click(function(){
    var row=$(this).parent();
    //un-highlight any previously row
    $("table#selectMenu tr").removeClass("selectedRow");
    //highlight current row
    $(row).addClass("selectedRow");

    //get credits (from last td)
    var c=$(row).children(":last").text();
    //show credits required in span below table
    $("span#credits").text(c);
    $("#creditsValue").attr("value",c);
    })
});
</script>
```